# Storing data offline on a Node.js backend for Android

Tags: javascript, android, node.js, mongodb

I am running node.js server side with MongoDB and I like the use of the NoSQL databases as it is easy to run with.

The android app I am creating stores data into the database from Node.js when it is online, but I want to have a functionality to retrive data offline from the DB?

I have a app.post set up, but I am still not sure how to communicate server-side offline?

Comment: Can you explain a little more? What does offline/online mean in this context?

Comment: Please explain about your  little bit more. People here are having a hard time understanding what your problem is, and offline/online retrieval means.

Answer (score 0):

You **can't communicate**  server when **off-line**.

Suggestion : When sever is off-line you have to store data in android database.